# Magento 2.3.2 Error XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document

Tags: error, magento2.3, xml

I need for a programm to (webwinkelfacturen.nl) to read my taxrates so I can be pushed in an accountingsystem. But I am getting this error when I want to call `domainname/ndex.php/rest/V1/taxRates`

I am getting this error:

> This page contains the following errors:
>  error on line 2 at
>   column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the
>   document
>  Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

The programm is using this to get the taxrates:

> https://www.bakmina.com/index.php/rest/V1/taxRates/search?searchCriteria%5Bpage_size%5D=100

And that gives the same error. What is this ? And how can I FIX it ?

Comment: Recently in which xml files you are working ?

Comment: No, so is gonna be a real puzzle if I don't know where to look. But where can I find that V1 directory ? Maybe I can start there.

Comment: Anybody maybe an idea where to find it ? Or it will be hell I am afraid if I have to check all xml files on the reserver